# Construct symmetric block matrix in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-ufunc

For example, I got the following 2D array

```py
a= np.array([[1,2,3],
[2,5,6],
[3,6,9]])
```

If I know the dimension of each block square matrix of diagonal, i.e

```py
2,3,2
```

How can I generate the following 2D block array

```py
[[1,1,2,2,2,3,3],
[1,1,2,2,2,3,3],
[2,2,5,5,5,6,6],
[2,2,5,5,5,6,6],
[2,2,5,5,5,6,6],
[3,3,6,6,6,9,9],
[3,3,6,6,6,9,9]]
```

Comment: All of your 2-tuples in `(2,2),(3,3),(2,2)` have both elements equal. It would be worth giving an example with non-equal elements so that we can see which way round they are meant to work. Or if the two elements *must* be equal, then it would be better to specify it only once, i.e. `2,3,2`.

Comment: @alaniwi OK, thank you for your advice, I just change the question

Comment: `a.repeat([2,3,2],1).repeat([2,3,2],0)`

Comment: @PaulPanzer Nice.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Amazing, thank you so much